# php sort multimentional array with numeric keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm making an event calendar. Everything needs to be sorted chronologically.

This is the array I'm currently sorting:

```
$years = array(
    2018 => array(
        01 => array(),
        02 => array()
    ),
    2017 => array(,
        02 => array()
        01 => array()
    )
);
```

I originally have a larger array used to populate this `$years`.

Using `ksort`, I've sorted my `years` correctly, i.e. they are in chronological order. However, I can't sort my third level (see in `2017`, my array is `02,01` whereas it should read `01,02`). The last level or the array (such as `2017 > 02`) is sorted correctly, this is not an issue, as these are sorted by content within each of them.

I've tried `array_multisort`, `ksort`, `usort` and simply `sort` but none allow me to sort my keys as they are numeric.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about iterating through the children elements, sorting them with `ksort()` as well:

```
<?php
$years = array(
    2018 => array(
        01 => array(),
        02 => array()
    ),
    2017 => array(
        02 => array(),
        01 => array()
    )
);
ksort($years);
foreach ($years as &$year) {
    ksort($year);
}
var_dump($years);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FLbtg)

Comment: Oh, okay, I see my issue here, the use of `&` before my `$year` solves it. It's a bit too quick to mark the answer as accepted. May I ask what the `&` character does in this scenario?

Comment: It's using the element as a reference. This means, it will modify the actual `$year` array instead of simply returning a modified copy. Read about this [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this one will be helpful. Here we are using [`ksort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) for sorting array on the basis of keys.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/863248)

```
ksort($years);
$result=array_map(
  function($array)  {
       ksort($array);
       return $array;
  },
  $years);
```

Comment: Since this does solve the issue, I've upvoted. However, I have used [ishegg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266206/php-sort-multimentional-array-with-numeric-keys/46266251#46266251), therefore I will be marking that answer as the solution. Thanks for your input!

Comment: @Akintunde Oh Thanks, Good to here this.. :)